# How to use another keystore in the same app on Google Play

Tags: android, react-native, google-play, expo, hybrid-mobile-app

We began to develop an app using Expo then push it to Google Play. It is still on Google Play now.

Recently, we decided to use react-native from scratch (without eject expo, it is a new project with the same functionalities with the old one, please don't ask me explain why, it is a hard decision from our team).

Now we try to upload a new release on the same project as the old one on Google Play and Google said that our app signing key has changed.

We know that is true but we don't know how to re-use the old keystore. In the old expo-project, we found a find name *.jks, but don't remember its password and its key alias.

We'd like to know if it is possible to change the app signing key on Google play, to be able to keep using the old project, instead of creating a new project.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you change the app package id (eg. com.app.my)?

Answer (score 1):

If you’ve lost your private upload key, or it’s been compromised, you can create a new one, and then ask your account owner to [contact support to reset the key](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs). make sure your account owner attaches the upload_certificate.pem file.

After that google support team would register the new upload key, you will receive an email, and then you can update your keystores and register your key with API providers.